# The life cycle of money

Tags: money-supply

Is all the money created by a central bank destroyed after a period of time ?

ie : is all the money in the system debt or is there an amount of money that exist "forever" ?

Comment: Are you talking about currency (M0) or the abstract concept of money that is represented by numbers in ledgers?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about a currency. if we suppose that nobody take loans anymore, and all the loans are repaid, is that mean that there will be no money in the system?

Comment: This question should be edited to make sense or be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer but avoiding discussion of M1, M2 etc, too pedantic.

I don't believe you are asking about the lifetime of either coins or paper money. I think you are referencing the fractional reserve system, and how a good portion of the total money supply is created by the banks lending out their deposits in effect 'creating' money. My answer to you is that if all loans were simply paid off, no mortgages, no car loans, etc, the total money in the system would collapse to some reasonable fraction of what it is today, 10% or a bit less. This comes from the fact that the [reserve requirement for most large banks is 10%](http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/reservereq.htm). 
I'm referencing money, but not bills or coins. Think about what you make in a year. How much do you touch as paper money? For my wife and me, it's no more than a few percent. Most goes from a direct deposit to online payments. So this would be the subject of a different question altogether. 
Let me know if this addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing JohnF, and assuming you mean the physical, rather than abstract meaning of money?  The abstract concept obviously isn't replaced (unless the currency is discredited, or like the creation of the Euro which saw local currencies abandoned).

The actual bits of paper are regularly collected, shredded (into itty-bitty-bits) and destroyed.  Coinage tends to last a lot longer, but it also collected and melted down eventually.

Depends on the country, though.  No doubt, many people who took a gap year to go travelling in points diverse came across countries where the money is a sort of brown-grey smudge you hold with care in thick wadges.

The more modern economies replace paper money on a dedicated cycle ([around three years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banknote#Destruction) according to Wikipedia, anyway).

Comment: A certian amount of money is also taken out of circulation through normal use(Burned, buried, throw out, etc).